# TImageEnView not able to display some .jpg file

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

`pImageEnView.IO.LoadFromFileJPEG(pFileName)` doesnt not display some of the .jpg images but when i use  `pImageEnView.IO.LoadFromFileAuto(pFileName)` the image are visible this also happened when i was using `pImageEnView.IO.LoadFromFileBMP(pFileName)` for .bmp file

Comment: How can we reproduce this problem? "doesnt not display" is not a problem description. What is the specific problem you're having? Do you get an error message? If so, what is the exact message you're getting? If you want help here, you're going to need to be specific in your questions and provide details so we can do so.

Comment: I dont get any error message, the image gets loaded as a thumbnail but is not visible.This happens only for some images but it works fine for other images with same extensions.

Comment: tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2mdvu8&s=5#.UsZUyNIW2VM is the image that is not visible using ImageEnView.IO.LoadFromFileJPEG(pFileName) but if i crop the same image it is visible using the same function

Comment: I'm not sure how you think an image of an image that won't load would be helpful to us. "My car doesn't work. Here's a picture of a car of the same make and model. What could be wrong?"

Comment: That is not the image of image that is the actual image that is not visible....... Look i am completely new to this site....and i agree i am not able to clearly state my problem... I just want to ask that is there any problem in pImageEnView.IO.LoadFromFileJPEG function of the component because i googled quite alot and i read smthing that states there is a problem in the actual code of this function that i am using

Answer (score 2):

The explanation that fits the symptoms is that the file format does not match the file extension. Perhaps you have a .jpg file that is really a Windows bitmap file. Or some other format.

Debug and diagnose this by looking at the files in a hex editor. All common image file formats begin with a header that identifies the format.

Comment: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2mdvu8&s=5#.UsZUyNIW2VM is the image that is not visible using ImageEnView.IO.LoadFromFileJPEG(pFileName) but if i crop the same image it is visible using the same function

Comment: look at the first few bytes in a hex editor and tell us what they are

Comment: 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49 48 44 52 is the first line

Comment: So there's your answer. It's a PNG file: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics

Comment: @suri1 Are you still in need of help?

Comment: Open with the paint for example.. and try to save with a real jpg format.. not just changing the extension.